# Jhipster 4 - package dev

Tags: angular, spring-boot, webpack, jhipster

I have a Jhipster 4 project using Angular2. I need to package the app but with the dev profile.
When I run the command mvnw -Pdev package the backend part wokrks, but the front-end don't.
Is there any way to package the app with the dev profile and with the graphical elements (html, css, js)?

Or there's any way to use mvnw -Pprod package skipping the Phanton and Jasmine tests?

I've managed to run my application removing karma from my scripts in package.json. But when I run the application with the prod profile it still with the backend workin but my index is a white page.
The files are genereted at the target/www, but I get this error: "Error: moduleId should be a string in "e".

Full error:

"Error: moduleId should be a string in "e". See link for more information.
If you're using Webpack you should inline the template and the styles, see link.
    at e.d (file:///C:/Users/Paulo%20Henrique/Desktop/project/company%20delivery/target/www/e349871cf451e0282ba9.polyfills.bundle.js:50:1731)
    at e [as constructor] (file:///C:/Users/Paulo%20Henrique/Desktop/project/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:1714:420)
    at new e (file:///C:/Users/Paulo%20Henrique/Desktop/project/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:59:749)
    at s (file:///C:/Users/Paulo%20Henrique/Desktop/project/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:305:6242)
    at t._loadDirectiveMetadata (file:///C:/Users/Paulo%20Henrique/Desktop/project/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:312:4000)
    at file:///C:/Users/Paulo%20Henrique/Desktop/project/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:312:7106
    at Array.forEach ()
    at t.loadNgModuleDirectiveAndPipeMetadata (file:///C:/Users/Paulo%20Henrique/Desktop/project/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:312:7078)
    at file:///C:/Users/Paulo%20Henrique/Desktop/project/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:1105:2432
    at Array.forEach ()
    at t._loadModules (file:///C:/Users/Paulo%20Henrique/Desktop/project/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:1105:2385)
    at t._compileModuleAndComponents (file:///C:/Users/Paulo%20Henrique/Desktop/project/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:1105:1803)
    at t.compileModuleAsync (file:///C:/Users/Paulo%20Henrique/Desktop/project/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:1105:1226)
    at e._bootstrapModuleWithZone (file:///C:/Users/Paulo%20Henrique/Desktop/project/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:762:2664)
    at e.bootstrapModule (file:///C:/Users/Paulo%20Henrique/Desktop/project/company%20delivery/target/www/vendor.dll.js:762:2289)"

Node version: v6.10.1

Comment: What does not work with `mvnw -Pdev package`? Please clarify your question. For the second part, it's easy just look at how the dev and prod profiles configure the frontend-maven-plugin in the pom.xml.

Comment: With mvnw Pdev package the backend (Java) works fine. But the Angular part is not built

Comment: Because it must be built by by yarn (try `yarn webpack:build:main`) but the angular app will be bundled and I'm not sure that's what you want. Please clarify your expectations.

Comment: The webpack:buil wasn't in the maven goal so I had to run webpack:build first and copy the files to target/www. This works fine, but too slow.
When I run npm run webpack:prod the files are genereted at the target/www, but I get this error:
"Error: moduleId should be a string in "e".
Should I open a new question?

Comment: This error message is not very helpful without stack trace and env details like node version.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I've provided more details on the question